# using local package in multiple projects in meteor

Tags: meteor, meteor-packages

I am trying to use same package and same server for multiple projects in meteor. I am a novice so request you to correct me where I am going wrong.
I am using this package called 'https://github.com/CulturalMe/meteor-slingshot/' to upload files in S3 in project A. I have another project B. I have created a folder called 'server' in my root directory and have created a symbolic link to this 'server' folder from both A and B. Everything works fine except for those packages that are used in the server.

1. I made a folder called 'packages' in my root directory.
2. I cloned the above package in this directory called 'packages'.
3. Then I set the environment variable export `PACKAGE_DIRS='/home/XXX/projects/XXXX/packages/'`
4. When I run project B, I am getting an error as `ReferenceError: Slingshot is not defined`

As far as I know, meteor is supposed to look for this package in environment variable, so why am I getting this message

Comment: please just do as the documentation tells you to: `meteor add edgee:slingshot`, or are you editing the package content and want to share that modified version across projects?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create an symbolic link of each package's folder under different projects' `packages` folder. Just like [the way to test your own package](https://atmospherejs.com/i/publishing)